# Binding to array item works only once

Tags: angular

I am using `Angular 2.0.0-rc.5` and I have a component which looks like this:

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
         [style.width]="getItemWeight(i)">

          <!--
          Also I tried to bind it like this: [style.width]="(weights[i]*100)+'%'"
          But it binds only once anyway :-(
          -->

        ...
    </div>
    `
})
class MyComponent {

    private weights : number[] = [];

    @Input() items : any[] = [];

    /*
    Here I have some logic which alters this.weights (or even replaces it - I tried both ways).
    */

    private getItemWeight(index : number) : string {
        return `${this.weights[index] * 100}%`;
    }
}
```

I have an `items` array and corresponding private `weights` array.
All works good except binding to `weights` - it sets style once, but, for some reasons, not updates it when `weights` array altered or even replaced.

Also I want to mention, that it is not connected with zones and so on - I tested it with simple string variable, which was declared in the same way and altered in the same place - all works perfectly with it and I presume that my problem connected with the fact that `weights` is array.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tQMcbtIWK9x1OnADS1Pu?p=preview. So the problem is probably elsewhere. Check your console for errors, and post a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it really works. It was a bug in my code - ngOnChanges accidentaly executes and reinitialize my array to default values.

Comment: Guys, sorry for your wasted time, it looks like problem was caused by stupid mistake...